# Static Blocks in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

To test Network Encoding/Decoding Logic, I have a pair of tests in Java and JavaScript. For these tests, I have Data Providers which are pretty much just a bunch of Constants.

Now, In Java, I have a Data Provider that uses a static block to create a random byte array for one of the classes I want to test, like this:

```
    public static final byte[] BYTE_ARRAY_RANDOM = new byte[4 * 1024];
    static {
        new Random().nextBytes(BYTE_ARRAY_RANDOM);
    }
    public static final FileBody FILE_BODY_RANDOM = new FileBody(BYTE_ARRAY_RANDOM);
```

Now I want to mirror this in TypeScript. I have tried this, but that causes a compiler error because I am apparently doing the static block wrong:

```
    public static BYTE_ARRAY_RANDOM: Uint8Array = new Uint8Array(4 * 1024);
    static {
        BYTE_ARRAY_RANDOM.set(pseudoRandomBytes(bytes.length));
    }
    public static FILE_BODY_RANDOM: FileBody = new FileBody(TestDataProvider.BYTE_ARRAY_RANDOM);
```

I have also tried a number of other approaches, but thus far haven't been able to work out a solution.

So, how do I do this in JavaScript? What I want is to create a Constant that provides an arbitrary random byte array every time the tests are run.

Or to ask this another way: How can I turn this static in TypeScript?

```
    let bytes = new Uint8Array(4 * 1024);
    bytes.set(pseudoRandomBytes(bytes.length));
    let fileBody = new FileBody(bytes);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think TypeScript supports static block. For your particular case, you can create a helper function:

```js
class Foo {
    public static bytes = createRandomBytes(4 * 1024);
    public static fileBody = new FileBody(Foo.bytes);
}

function createRandomBytes(length: number) {
    const bytes = new Uint8Array(length);
    bytes.set(pseudoRandomBytes(bytes.length));
    return bytes;
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can use a static helper function

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript does support static initialization blocks, as of TypeScript 4.4. (available August 2021)

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-4-rc/#static-blocks

It's also supported in JavaScript:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Static_initialization_blocks

The syntax is as you would expect, ie:

```
static {
    // Your code here
}
```